# Error ARC 'release' is unavailable error becomes "expression result unused'

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, release

I know that this is a similar question to the ARC deprecated code however, I have some old code from NIB days that I am upgrading to Storyboards and in doing so, the code revisions are causing me some issues.

In the code below:

```
- (void)audioSound {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound-file" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if(theAudioSound)[theAudioSound release];
    theAudioSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudioSound.volume = 0.30;
    [theAudioSound play];
}
```

I get the ARC problem; After many attempts to find a solution I can only find the following advice.

```
   Delete the 'release'
```

If I do delete the release - depending on how I delete it - I get the following error messages.

from

```
if(theAudioSound)[theAudioSound release];
```

to

```
if(theAudioSound)[theAudioSound];
```

the Error is "Expected Identifier"

and from

```
if(theAudioSound)[theAudioSound];
```

to

```
if(theAudioSound)theAudioSound;
```

the Warning is "Expression Result Unused"

if I use the second of the two changes will it work? 
and if not; what would I need to do to change the code so that it does work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `release` actually releases( decreases the retain count) here, if any object has already has been created. But in ARC, you don't have to `release` it manually.

I suggest clearing the `AVAudioPlayer` instance in stead of `release`, and it will work. So the code will look like:

```
if(theAudioSound) {
    theAudioSound = nil;
}
```

OR

Simply delete or comment out the line `if(theAudioSound)[theAudioSound release];` like:

`// if(theAudioSound)[theAudioSound release];`

And continue with the rest of codes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if(theAudioSound)[theAudioSound release];
```

You need to totally comment out that line for this to work.

Actually this is another way of writing following

```
        if(theAudioSound)
    {
        [theAudioSound release];
    }
```

If you simply delete `release`, that would generate a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

"Delete the 'release'" means you don't need to release it. So, you just remove the line or comment in. That's just all I think.

```
- (void)audioSound {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound-file" ofType:@"mp3"];
    //if(theAudioSound)[theAudioSound release];
    theAudioSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudioSound.volume = 0.30;
    [theAudioSound play];
}
```